# Git rebase wants me to resolve conflicts after rerere-train script is applied

Tags: git

This is what I did:

```
git init
touch file
git add file
git commit -m 'add file'
git checkout -b 'branch1'
rm file
git add file
git commit -m 'delete file'
git checkout master
echo 'content' > file
git add file
git commit -m 'edit file'
git merge 'branch1'
git add file
git commit -m 'solve conflict'
```

`git log --oneline` gives me this:

```
38a9e5a (HEAD -> master) resolve conflict
4d07d5f edit file
8f7a049 (branch1) delete file
40db0ce add file
```

Now, I want to use `git rebase` to change commit's message. After running: `git rebase -i --root` I performed `reword`, but in result I got an error:

```
error: could not apply 8f7a049... delete file
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 8f7a049... delete file
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file deleted in 8f7a049 (delete file) and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of file left in tree.
```

After searching about this I learned that `git rebase` won't by default resolve conflicts, that were already resolved by me. I have to resolve them again, or use `rerere` command. I went with second solution, which requires [rerere-train.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89bece5c8c96f0b962cfc89e63f82d603fd60bed/contrib/rerere-train.sh):

```
git config --global rerere.enabled 1
./rerere-train.sh --all
```

Unfortunately, `git rebase HEAD~1` still wants me to resolve conflict. Why?

Comment: A "modify/delete" conflict is a separate *kind* of conflict; `git rerere` does not handle these at all. (It probably should but the mechanism that `git rerere` uses is inadequate.)

Comment: @torek but in my "real" scenario after using `git rebase` I have to solve like 50 conflicts. I already resolved them in past, and now I have to do this again, because `rebase/rerere` doesn't know how to deal with modify/delete conflicts?

Comment: Yes. That's why I say it probably should.